# Error installing Rails (after installing nearly 20 dlls one by one) rl_attempted_completion_over (readline.dll)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby

Each time I typed: gem install rails it asked me for a dll. SO I downloaded the following:

```
datasvcs.dll, icudt24l.dll, icuin24.dll, icuio24.dll, icuuc24.dll,
    libeay32.dll, libmex.dll, libmwservices.dll, libmx.dll, libut.dll,
    libz.dll, mpath.dll, msvcrt-ruby191.dll, mvalue.dll, m_dispatcher.dll,
    nscrt.dll, readline.dll, ssleay32.dll, xerces-c_2_1_0.dll, zlib.dll.
```

In the end it said: can't find this location rl_attempted_completion_over (readline.dll)

(I already have readline.dll!)

I'm using Windows XP

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using (1.8.6 from Installer, 1.9)? Is it 64 bit Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the exact same "rl_attempted_completion_over" problem after installing Ruby 1.9.1p376 on a Windows 7 machine that was running Ruby 1.8.6 just fine. I manually downloaded all of the dlls from econsultant.com/dll-database/ Unfortunately, the readline.dll they have is not correct. Their dll was 5,632 bytes. The dll Ruby requires is 136,192 bytes in size. I found the correct dll at http://jarp.does.notwork.org/win32/readline-4.3-2-mswin32.zip. Copy this dll to a path in your environment. I placed my dlls in the Ruby's bin directory. After having done these steps and running a few tests with Sinatra and Rails, this appears to have resolved the problem.